# using addEventListener to make images appear by clicking in certain areas in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, addeventlistener

I have been building a timeline with Canvas and Javascript. I'm pretty inexperienced and have been struggling on how to make the addEventListener react to certain co-ordinates in a canvas.
This is what I'm actually working on: http://january.thecarma.net/timelinexp/index.html

What I'm trying to do is when you click in one of the year circles, 3 pngs pop up. I've managed to make them appear when clicking anywhere on the canvas, but I don't know how to tell addEventListener to only make the pngs appear when the user clicks in certain co-ordinates (Eg:the circles). The other part of the problem is if the user clicks onto another circle I want the previous circle's pngs to disappear and the newly clicked circle's pngs to appear.

addEventListener as it is now:

```
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) { 
        //below are the images I've loaded and want to use
        var photo = new Image();
        photo.src = "photo.png";
        var papers = new Image();
        papers.src = "papers.png";
        var collab = new Image();
        collab.src = "collab.png";
        ctx.drawImage(photo, 390, 230, 80, 80);
        ctx.drawImage(papers, 530, 230, 80, 80);    
        ctx.drawImage(collab, 530, 280, 80, 80);
    });
```

I had the idea that if I loaded up these co-ords into an array, and then thru the event handler used a For Loop or Conditional Statement (or both?) to cycle thru to find the matching the co-ords. If they match, the pngs appear. If they don't, nothing happens. In short:

```
var mouseCo = [{x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4}, <------circle1 
               {x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4}, <------circle2 
               {x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4}]; <------circle3
```

and adding anymore circles and their co-ords as I need. The co-ords come from the picture I linked: http://imgur.com/RXIwMdO

I know that looks pretty clumsy and convuluted, but I wasn't sure how else to get the co-ords.

Anyway after loading co-ords in the array known as mouseCo, I take mouseCo and run it thru addEventListener:

```
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) { 
//put here either a for loop or conditional statment (maybe both?) to run thru the array, check if
//co-ords click match the ones in the array and if so, show pngs, if not, do nothing.
});
```

What do you think? And if there's a better/faster way of doing it, I'm all ears - I suspect there's probably a much easier and less convulted way of doing this but I'm a noob :/.
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You must get the `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` from the event handler. These offsets, begin from `0,0` at the top left corner of the element, and then they are increased by the amount of the distance in pixels your mouse is. Then you know where your mouse is clicked. Geometry will help you to know if you are inside the bounds. For circles you only need origin point and radius. As you said you loop through the array with the circles and check in each one if you are in, you may not stop because your mouse may be in 2 or more bounds.